# Memory optimized data base and table variable

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016, database-administration, memory-optimized-tables

After looking into different groups/discussions i didn't found any satisfactory answer of my question,

I have around 1.5 TB size Sql server database in production, and there is also a transaction replication set on this database, 
In order to add/migrate disk based to memory optimized table we have to only create a file group with memory optimized data or any other setting on whole database?

If we only use memory optimized table variables only that will be not durable, do we need to apply same setting on complete database?

And is there will be any performance gain to use in memory table variables in non-native compile store procedure?

And most important, What will be effect on replication? we can not add durable memory optimized table in replication? but what about file group or any other setting on database if only made on primary database?

Thank you

Comment: It is not possible to simply migrate to Memory Optimized Tables in this fashion. It requires a lot of changes to your entire architecture. Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/memory-optimized-tables

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to move your whole 1.5 TB of data in In Memory? If yes - it is not advised because of its size. Further, settings directly at DB levels, will not help. There are certain steps to follow. Refer MSDN.

Are you on replication or Always On?

.